# Deleting lucene document by id

Tags: lucene

How can I delete single document from Lucene index?
There's no method deleteDocument(int docId) and I can't find a query that selects just one document based on docId...

using Lucene 4.10.3
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You will see docId (int) never in the public api, because docId can change with each commit (and merge ...).
So you have to use [deleteDocuments(Term)](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#deleteDocuments(org.apache.lucene.index.Term)).

In solr you can [deleteById](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_4_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrClient.html#deleteById(java.lang.String)) but internally this is the same as `deleteDocuments(new Term("id",id))`

Answer (score 0):

While merging multiple shards into one big core, I accidentally merged two time the same core, resulting in group of documents having the same value for the id field. To solve the problem, I used this code to delete documents by their positional id:

```
public class IndexCleaner {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(args[0]));
        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_4_10_4, null));
        IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(writer, false);) {
      int numDocs = reader.numDocs();
      Set<String> items = new HashSet<>(numDocs);
      for (int i = numDocs - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        String id = reader.document(i).get("id");
        if (items.contains(id)) {
          writer.tryDeleteDocument(reader, i);
          System.out.println("Document with id \"" + id + "\" marked for deletion");
        }
        else {
          items.add(id);
        }
      }

      writer.commit();
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```